# fixing undefined index notice

Tags: php

I'm getting an undefined index notice, but can't figure out how to fix it.

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/html/book_details.php on line 10
```

This is the code that's having problems:

```
    // query for the listing
$listing = query("SELECT name, author, id, edition, price, course, date FROM books WHERE submission = ?", $_GET["submission"]); 

// query for the email of the seller
$seller = query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = ?", $listing["id"]);
```

Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: I bet there is no `"id"` in `$listing`.

Comment: Is query a custom function or does this belong to a specific database library?  Try using using `print_r( $listing )` to see what values `$listing` has.

Comment: What is `query()`?  Does it return the *result* of the query?

Comment: Why don't you debug your code ?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($listing)` first and see what you're really getting back.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the array returned from your first query, `$listing` doesn't have an element with the key `id`.

I suspect this would happen if there was no record in the database for whatever was passed in as the `submission` GET parameter.  Hard to say for sure though without knowing how the `query()` function was written.